# How can I do this Fulltext search within an INNER JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, search, join, full-text-search

I have two tables that I'm joining (in order to get the username from, I'm joining them both on user_id).

Here is my **Accounts** table structure:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| user_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| username  | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| email     | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| timestamp | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| hashed_pw | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| active    | char(32)         | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Here is my **Submissions** table structure

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| description | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| source      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| category    | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| user_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| submit_ip   | int(4) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| timestamp   | timestamp        | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| thumbnail   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Right now, I'm using the following query to get what I need, and it's working fine:

```
SELECT Submissions.title, Submissions.description, Submissions.timestamp,
Accounts.user_id 

FROM `Submissions` 

INNER JOIN `Accounts` ON 

Submissions.user_id=Accounts.user_id;
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  title: IJL that one of the men who discovered the stratosphere had a very unfortunate 
name.
description: 
  timestamp: 2011-04-27 01:43:54
    user_id: 8
*************************** 2. row ***************************
      title: IJL that nuclear reactors actually glow blue.
description: Testing the description out on this one
  timestamp: 2011-04-27 02:05:12
    user_id: 8
```

I'd like to perform a fulltext search on the result set on both the Submissions.title and Submissions.description like:

```
WHERE MATCH (Submissions.title, Submissions.description) AGAINST (?)
```

How could I add this to my current query to get the desired result?

Comment: did you tried putting in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first do this

```
ALTER TABLE Submissions ADD FULLTEXT(title, description);
```

this will add fulltext search for this two columns

this do this

```
WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST (’keyword’);
```

Comment: Thanks. Dumb mistake on my part.. I forgot the quotes around the against clause. Thanks.